# ASP.Net Web Service not allowing Windows Service to Call A Function

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services

I have a Windows XP (SP3) development box with IIS on it.  I have my ASP.Net website setup in IIS and have tested access to it.  I created a Windows Service project which has a web reference to the local IIS and picks up the wsdl and displays all of the functions properly.  I add my code for a timer to execute a specific function on the web service that synchronizes data.  I have a few service log entries that are made to keep track of the progress of each step and when it attempts to execute the web service function, it does nothing.  I followed an MSDN example of [how to schedule ASP.Net web service code in a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx) but after following their example, mine does not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am assuming the Local System account that the service is using to login does not have access to the web service?  If this is the case, can someone tell me how to grant access for the local system account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regular user account to run your windows service instead of the built in Local System account. In the first instance, use your own account, just to make sure it works.
Once you've established that your problem is permissions related, then go ahead and create a specific user account for running your service.

If it ever gets to the stage where your windows service and ASP.Net web service run on different boxes, then the built in Local System account won't be appropriate anyway.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the heads-up.  I marked this as the answer as it did lead me to the answer.  The local system account was fine but what that DID do for me was it ruled out an issue with the account logging into the service.  The next step was to check permissions with IIS.  I am developing in Visual Studio so the IIS was the cassini server.  I also have IIS 7.5 Express for 2010 installed and attempted to use both but was unsuccessful.  Only solution was to add my web service to IIS installed on XP.  This was not a bad thing because it mimic'd the actual production setup.  Thanks again!